# displaying double in messagebox

Tags: c, messagebox, printf

I'm having issues with converting a double to a string, and then to a message box. From what i've read, sprintf is (loosely, but not the best choice due to certain points) the function i want from . Here's my example code, but i'm not sure where i'm going wrong.

```
DOUBLE time;
char timearray[30];
time = (double)(end.QuadPart - st.QuadPart)/(double)freq.QuadPart;
sprintf(timearray, "%lf", time);
```

where'd i go from here? i've tried things like;

```
MessageBox(NULL, timearray, TEXT("mb"), MB_OK);
```

But this gives the following error on the timearray parameter:
error of type "*char" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR".

Any ideas as to where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your project is set to use wide (Unicode) characters by default, so you should use `wchar_t` and `wsprintf` (better, `wnsprintf`).

```
double time;
wchar_t buffer[30];
time = (double)(end.QuadPart - st.QuadPart)/(double)freq.QuadPart;
_snwprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(*buffer), L"%lf", time);
MessageBoxW(NULL, buffer, L"mb", MB_OK);
```

or, if you want to use the `TCHAR`s:

```
double time;
TCHAR buffer[30];
time = (double)(end.QuadPart - st.QuadPart)/(double)freq.QuadPart;
_sntprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(*buffer), _T("%lf"), time);
MessageBox(NULL, buffer, _T("mb"), MB_OK);
```

Comment: upon using wnsprintf i'm getting an identifier "wnsprintf" is undefined error message. is there something i'm missing? i assumed this was included in <stdio.h> but i could be wrong.

Comment: edit : i think you meant to write just wsprintf. although this gives me an error on the first "sizeof(buffer)", saying that type unsigned int is incompatible.

Comment: Sorry, it's `_snwprintf`. `wsprintf ` is standard, but doesn't have buffer bounds checking so you should avoid it.